# mongodo index within a document or only across a document collection

Tags: mongodb

I am collecting data from a streaming API and I want to create a real-time analytics dashboard. Every time a new record appears at the end of the stream I update a counter in the below document.

From a design perspective. Am I correct to use only one document, like in the below example?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5238beb4d4bed9e444c99978"),
    "counts" : {
        "hours" : {
            "1" : 835,
            "2" : 1007,
            .
                    .
                    .
                    "3" : 174,
         }
}
```

The benefit with this approach is that only one document needs to be sent to the real-time analytics dashboard. Also after a year this document would have only 365 * 24 fields, 1 for each hour in that year?

What about indexing? Can I create an index on counts.hours if I only have one document? Or do indexes only work across collections in mongodb? Do indexes help with finding documents faster or also fields inside documents?

If I could create an index on counts.hours, then the counter increment process could find the correct hour to increment (per new document at the end of the stream) much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create indexes in fields embedded in a document. In the case above:

```
yourCollection.ensureIndex({ 'counts.hours':1 });
```

The index will help you optimize queries to return documents based on 'counts.hours' field.

```
youCollection.find({ 'count.hours':1 });
```

Your data structure design should depend on the kind of queries and updates you are planning to do. In the case you described I imagine you will be adding members to the 'hours' object, updates like that might be expensive since MongoDB pads each collection record optimizing for the case where the record size is stable across updates.